# What is the real equivalent(s) of the word "речь"?

Tags: перевод, значения

[image: What is real equivalent(s) of the word "речь" on the picture?]

What is the real equivalent(s) of the word "речь" on the picture?

Comment: "о чём идёт речь" = "what is the subject" = "о чём тут говорят".

Comment: @НадеждаТарашкевич you meant that "речь" means subject? or it means "subject" here and could be different in different contexts? and is the word "speech" wrong translation for it?

Comment: "речь" means "talking" here. "О чём идёт речь" cannot be translated literally, word-by-word. It's more like idiom.

Comment: @НадеждаТарашкевич i certainly got it after i read "it's more like idiom"! because there is a similar idiom in my native language. спасибо вам большое!

Comment: @IsmailYilmaz is it a homework? Nobody will help you to do your homework.

Comment: @shabunc of course not homework! i just try to learn a  real equivalent(s) of a word as you see on the question title. thats all! and everything is enough simple not to be homework on the picture! isnt it?

Comment: @shabunc also i know the idea of this q&a community platform well! im a software developer and ive been using stackoverflow service of stack exchange company for a long time. ok i dont have that much reputations because there are already all answers for the questions that i wanted to ask and also there are answers for questions that i wanted to answer. please sir, im not that much bad to create a question to do my homework! and i've been livin here in spb for 4 months and i already know what is those conversations about! i just wanted to know the real equivalent of that word on my new book..

Answer (score 3):

The exact translation of `речь` would be `speech` or `talking`. But `о чем идет речь?` is an idiom (collocation?). The literal translation is `what is the speech about`, but more correct one is `what are they/you talking about`